# Linear layout inside Lineary layout in android

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to create a layout in android, when i create a linear layout inside a linear layout its getting added but not visible in the interface. here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Parent linear layout with vertical orientation -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="_baseline"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="5dip"
      android:text="@string/name" />

  <EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="top"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:ems="10" >

     <requestFocus />
  </EditText>

  <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
      android:text="@string/submit" />

  <!-- Child linear layout with horizontal orientation -->

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#2a2a2a"
      android:baselineAligned="_baseline"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Previous" android:padding="15dip" android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"/>

  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Next" android:padding="15dip" android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"/>  

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is no space for it, your `EditText` and `Button` are `match_parent` so pushing everything out.

Comment: android:orientation="horizontal" your parent layout has this property. change it to vertical

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ken,I did that change but still its not visible.

Comment: @BrijeshThakur i had it as vertical then the edittext comes in a separate line

Comment: Then How do you want it.. I will give you the working code.

Comment: Pls update the code if you have changed the first linearlayout to vertical and still didn't work.

Comment: Check my answer, it might help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this I think you want this type of UI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Parent linear layout with vertical orientation -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="5dip"
     android:text="@string/app_name" />

   <EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="top"
     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
   </EditText>

 </LinearLayout>

 <Button
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
   />

 <!-- Child linear layout with horizontal orientation -->

 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#2a2a2a"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Previous" android:padding="15dip" android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"/>

 <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Next" android:padding="15dip" android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"/>  

 </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

the prob. is that you want to TextView and EditText in single line for that you put parent LinearLayout in Horizontal orientation but because of that all content saperated in gorizontalway..

so, you need to parent Layout Orientation as Vertical and take new Layout in that for EditText and TextView for horizontal separation. and that new Layout you need in Horizontal Orientation.

Show your UI here:

[image: UI based on Above code.]

Answer (score 2):

Change the first Linear Layout orientation "vertical". It should be works..

Answer (score 1):

Your parent layout is showing the child layout, but it is out of view. Change the Parent's layout orientation to Vertical and it will be visible.

Make these changes..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="_baseline"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

To get edittext in the same line,

Create a child layout for textview and edittext and make its orientation as horizontal.. it will be in the same line

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="_baseline"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="_baseline"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="5dip"
      android:text="@string/name" />

  <EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="top"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:ems="10" >

     <requestFocus />
  </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

...
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your description as you posted question, You done mistake in orientation, In Comment you write

> < !-- Parent linear layout with vertical orientation  -->

but in LinearLayout you set Orientation

> android:orientation="horizontal"

make it to

> android:orientation="vertical"

and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Parent linear layout with vertical orientation -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="_baseline"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="5dip"
      android:text="@string/name" />

  <EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="top"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:ems="10" >

     <requestFocus />
  </EditText>

  <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
      android:text="@string/submit" />
</LinearLayout>

  <!-- Child linear layout with horizontal orientation -->

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#2a2a2a"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:baselineAligned="_baseline"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Previous" android:padding="15dip" android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"/>

  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Next" android:padding="15dip" android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"/>  

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```